# CRM 2011 - HTML emails displaying as plain text

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to send HTML formatted emails from CRM 2011. I've read many blogs online which suggest that it is as simple as just copying and pasting HTML source code into the email body, and it will render the HTML correctly.

When I try this, the html source code is displayed in the body field as text - CRM doesn't seem to be recognising that it is HTML?

A great example of this is if I follow the instructions on this blog

http://elvenprogrammer.themanaworld.org/stunning-html-rich-emails-dynamics-crm-2011/

I end up with `<HTML>`... as the body, not the nicely formatted HTML :(

Can anyone help?!

Comment: In most cases the editor you are copying from is the culprit. Try pasting your HTML source to good ol notepad first and copy from there to ensure you arrive with the right stuff when pasting into the CRM email (template) editor.

Comment: Yeah I'm copying from Notepad++ so it should just be plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this on a crm 2011 on premise instance and it worked. Try this:

1. Open your HTML source in a web browser, it should appear just like you want the end result to be
2. Select All
3. Copy
4. Open up an E-mail template
5. Paste

I was able to get a nicely formatted version of the e-mail visible in the body.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I described I was doing and not having any joy :( do you know if there os perhaps a CRM system setting that prevents HTML emails? Also, could you confirm which browser you are using? And which version of which browser? For example IE10?

Comment: I did this in Windows 7 Enterprise, and using Firefox 17.0.4 (Kind of an old version). No setting in CRM 2011 to prevent HTML E-mail afaik. This is really odd. So to verify, you took your html source and opened it up in like IE, or Firefox and you saw the formatting come through properly? Text with visible formatting and not <b>text</b>. And when you copied and pasted that formatted text (not the source from notepad) it didn't work?

Comment: Ah ok! Sorted! I was copy and pasting the source code in rather than rendered output from the browser. Thanks!